# How can I modify the classicthesis margins only for the tables?

Tags: tables, margins, classicthesis

I would like to include some `longtable`s and `deluxetable`s in my PhD thesis written with `classicthesis`, but I find two problems:

1. The `deluxetable` is not floating.
2. The `longtable` is truncated on the left side if I use the portrait visualization and on the top if I use the landscape.

An example of the code in the case of the landscape

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lclrrrrrrrrcl}
%%%%
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

This is an example of my deluxetable:

```
\clearpage
\section{Cap.~\ref{cap: c1} Tables}
\begin{deluxetable}{llrrcll}
%%%%
\end{deluxetable}
```

The heading of my main source file:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                  
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}                                                    
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}       % per scrivere in italiano e in inglese;
\usepackage{indentfirst}                 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}       % indispensabili per la matematica
\usepackage[english]{varioref}            % riferimenti completi della pagina
\usepackage{deluxetable}
\usepackage{aalongtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,backref,square]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mnemonic,phd_thesis_bib}                                                
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}              % consigliato se si usa biblatex 
\usepackage[tight,english]{minitoc}       % per fare i miniindici
\usepackage{chngpage,calc}               
\usepackage{subfig}                       % sottofigure, sottotabelle
\usepackage{classicthesis-ldpkg}          
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,%         % numeri dei capitoli in Euler
            subfig,%                      % compatibilit‡ con subfig
            beramono,%                    % Bera Mono come font a spaziatura fissa
            eulermath,%                   % AMS Euler come font per la matematica
            pdfspacing%                   % migliora il riempimento di riga con PDFLaTeX
            ]{classicthesis}              % lo stile ClassicThesis

\usepackage[english]{arsclassica}         % modifica alcuni aspetti di ClassicThesis

\usepackage{tesi}                         % un pacchetto personale:
```

Any suggestion to overcome this problem?

I thought that if I may enlarge the margins only for the pages including the table it would work...but any other method would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We will need to see an MWE from you which shows your problems in an explicit case. Like this we will have to guess around or produce a complete example document for you just in order to help. If you provide some minimal code, you will get help very quick. Thank you.

Comment: The `deluxetable`s should float by default. Are you using something like `[h]` or alike? If the `longtable` is cropped, it seems to be too big. I would try to reformat the table or to use a `sidewaystable`. It will not look nice, if you change the margin for some pages.

Comment: I am not using any [h] and I would really like to avoid to re-format the tables. They are pretty long, wide and complex.

Comment: OK, but still we need an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). You do not show none of your two culprit tables, nor the documentclass but a lot of packages which have nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since `classicthesis` is built on [KOMAscript](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), you may try to use the built-in environment `addmargin`. The syntax is

```
\begin{addmargin}[left indentation]{indentation}
. . .
\end{addmargin}
```

Its description is at page 124 in the English [KOMAscript-manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) for further reference of it use.

Comment: Thanks! I tried but weirdly enough it only works for the caption...not for the rest of the table.

Comment: I solved it with \addtolength{\hoffset}{-3cm}

Comment: @laura Difficult to say what was causing that behaviour since you have not shared any code with us.

Comment: Just one little thing: The template classicthesis uses KOMA-script, the package `classicthesis` uses package `typearea` but smashes sensitive KOMA-internals to death.

Answer (score 0):

To add, because `classicthesis` has different margins for `even` and `odd` pages your table might not be positioned as intended using `addmargin`. To solve this, put the table in a `minipage` and use `ifthispageodd` to detect if the page is odd or even. Here is what I did

```
\ifthispageodd{
\begin{addmargin*}[-5em]{5em}
}{
\begin{addmargin*}[5em]{-5em}
}
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
{\fontsize{10.5pt}{10pt}\selectfont
%%add your arguments or content here
}
\end{minipage}
\end{addmargin*}
```

Of course, change the numbers as necessary.